# SED command error on MACOS X

Tags: macos, sed

I am trying to run this command on MacOSX terminal , which was initially intended to run on Linux

```
sed '1 i VISPATH=/mnt/local/gdrive/public/3DVis' init.txt >> ~/.bash_profile
```

but it gives me the error:

```
command i expects \ followed by text.
```

is there any way I could modify the above command to work on MacOSX terminal

Answer (score 37):

Shelter is right but there's another way to do it. You can use the bash `$'...'` quoting to interpret the escapes before passing the string to `sed`.

So:

```
         sed -iold '1i\'$'\n''text to prepend'$'\n' file.txt
                      ^^^^^^^^                     ^
                     / |\|||/ \                    |__ No need to reopen
                     | | \|/  |                          string to sed
     Tells sed to    | |  |   |
    escape the next _/ |  |   +-----------------------------+
         char          |  +-------------+                   |
                       |                |                   |
                  Close string   The  special bash   Reopen string to
                     to sed       newline char to      send to sed
                                    send to sed
```

*[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42328) on unix.stackexchange.com led me to this solution.*

Comment: This is the only solution that has worked for me on OS X in a bash script when using a variable. Not elegant but it works and should be portable. E.g. sed -i.tmp '2i\'$'\n'"$LINE"$'\n' $FILE

Comment: Much <3 for the explanation effort

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for to make my script work, thank you very much!

Answer (score 18):

Had the same problem and solved it with [brew](http://brew.sh/):

`brew install gnu-sed`

`gsed YOUR_USUAL_SED_COMMAND`

If you want to use the sed command, then you can set an alias:

`alias sed=gsed`

Comment: Alternatively, you can install `gnu-sed` with the option `--with-default-names` at the end, so the installed gnu-sed will have the `sed` name.

Answer (score 6):

The OSX `sed`s are based on older versions, you need to be much more literal in your directions to sed, AND you're lucky, in this case, `sed` is telling you exactly what to do. Untested as I don't have OSX, but try

```
sed '1 i\
VISPATH=/mnt/local/gdrive/public/3DVis

' init.txt >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Input via the `i` cmd is terminated by a blank line. Other sed instructions can follow after that. Note, NO chars after the `\` char!

Also, @StephenNiedzielski is right. Use the single quote chars to wrap your sed statements. (if you need variable expansion inside your sed  and can escape other uses of `$`, then you can also use dbl-quotes, but it's not recommended as a normal practices.

**edit**

As I understand now that you're doing this from the command-line, and not in a script or other editor, I have tested the above, and.... all I can say is that famous line from tech support ... "It works for me". If you're getting an error message

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: extra characters after command
```

then you almost certainly have added some character after the  `\`. I just tested that, and I got the above error message. (I'm using a linux version of sed, so the error messages are exactly the same). You should edit your question to include an exact cut-paste of your command line and the **new** error message. Using curly-single-quotes will not work.

IHTH

Comment: Tested on Mac OS X; it works, though the blank line is simply an empty command (to embed newlines in the text, you have to end the line with a backslash).

Comment: I try that and I got the following message: extra characters after \ at the end of i command

Comment: if you're using the `vi` or `vim` editor, turn on the list cmd, i.e. `:set list`, and I bet you see white-space characters after your `\\` char. You can't use a word processor to write a `sed` script ; -) !!! good luck.

Comment: I am using the MACOSX TERMINAL

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for that; it's implied by what you say, but to be explicit: don't end the *last* (or only) line of the text with \ - only needed for the *interior* lines of *multi-line* text.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I worked it out on OS X. In my case, I needed to prepend text to a file. Apparently, modern sed works like this:

```
sed -i '1i text to prepend' file.txt
```

But on OS X I had to do the following:

```
sed -i '' '1i\
text to prepend
' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you copied rich text. The single quotes should be straight not curly:

```
sed '1 i VISPATH=/mnt/local/gdrive/public/3DVis'
```

Comment: Good point about the quotes, but that alone doesn't solve the OP's OSX-specific problem.